# This Project Server 2010 feature requires at least Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0

Tags: ms-project-server-2010, project-web-access

I have encounter to following error when I try to access "Manage TimeSheet" and "Project Center" page in my pwa site:
 "Error
 This Project Server 2010 feature requires at least Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0.
  Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
 Correlation ID: 8f9f635b-c95b-4e2d-bd0a-e662c5d7b4ed"

I use Windows 8 (IE 10) and I have enable Compatibility mode.

This problem was first occurred when I installed and then uninstalled "Avant Browser" in my system.

I have read some texts that explain how this problem occurs and how to solve it.

Some of suggested solutions I have found are:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394699

http://epmsource.com/2012/06/05/windows-8-release-preview-and-project-server-2010/

But unfortunately none of them solved my problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about application usage and not programming something the poster owns or has access to.

Answer (score 1):

You have already added the URL to Compatability view, so I suggest to add the URL to local Intranet sites that solved the issue in my case.

For more details check [Project Server 2010 requires at least Microsoft Internet Explorer 7](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/28/project-server-2010-requires-at-least-microsoft-internet-explorer-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the User Agent as the links suggest?

I have also found that if there are restrictions or missing base Active X controls you may also get the "*Error This Project Server 2010 feature requires....*"

Not sure what they are but found that when trying to use the modern.ie virtual machines they would not work with Project Server 2010.